# How to get notification when the last observable finish emitting values?

Tags: angular, rxjs

We used to have one call to the API

```
reqFinanceDataWithFilters(req): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(env.baseUrl + req.url, req.filters)
    .pipe(map(this.extractResults));
}
```

The above request would return a giant json that takes time to build at the API level. So we decided to break it into 4 calls. Now we have:

```
reqViz.url = 'viz-data';
this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqViz)
    .pipe(...)

reqTableTop.url = 'summary-data';
this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqTableTop)
    .pipe(...)

reqTableMiddle.url = 'monthly-expenses';
this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqTableMiddle)
    .pipe(...)
```

So I have 4 independant calls to the API. The order the response for each of them is not important. All I want to know when the last one is done receiving response so that I can hide the **spinner** and display the page.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`forkJoin`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for this.

From **[LearnRxJS.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)**:

> ### Why use forkJoin?
>
> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all. In this way it is similar to how you might use Promise.all.
>
> Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed if you do not catch the error correctly on the inner observable. If you are only concerned with all inner observables completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

loading = true;
reqViz.url = 'viz-data';
const viz = this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqViz)
  .pipe(
    ...
    catchError(error => of(error))
  )

reqTableTop.url = 'summary-data';
const summary = this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqTableTop)
  .pipe(
    ...
    catchError(error => of(error))
  )

reqTableMiddle.url = 'monthly-expenses';
const monthy = this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqTableMiddle)
  .pipe(
    ...
    catchError(error => of(error))
  )
  
forkJoin(viz, summary, monthly)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      loading = false;
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 5):

```
forkJoin(/* your observalbes here */).subscribe(values => {
   // do stuff, all observables have completed
})
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 3):

`forkJoin` or `merge` can be interesting options, but another approach would be converting the sources to a stream via `from`, using `concatMap` to make the api call, and calling `finalize` at the end.

Which is better?  Well, it's really a matter of taste.  The stream from the pipe will contain one result at a time, instead of an array of all objects as would be the case with `forkJoin`.  If you need to run similar processes on each item after the api call then it would make sense to use this method.  For example, it would only be possible with this method if you wanted to show progress in the UI.

```
isRunning = true;
completedItems = 0;
progress = 0;
from([reqViz, reqTableTop, reqTableMiddle]).pipe(
   concatMap(req => this.reqFinanceDataWithFilters(reqTableMiddle)),
   tap(() => progress = (++completedItems) / 3),
   finalize(() => isRunning = false) // this is called at the end no matter what.
);
```